# SharePoint 2010 hosted wcf and castle windsor

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, castle-windsor

I am trying to work out how to host a wcf service in sharepoint 2010 which uses castle windsor. I can host my own standard custom web service without any issues by using one of the service factories from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521586(v=office.14).aspx.
Setting up a normal wcf service with castle windsor involves modifying the global.asax but, as this is not recommended for SharePoint, I have created an HttpModule which sets up the container and I have updated the web config to use it by creating a feature reciever.
My problem is where to go next. I am using the MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory for my service because that dynamically configures all of the endpoints for the service based on the IIS configuration but in order to use castle windsor it looks like it is necessary to change to using the supplied Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorServiceHostFactory. I have tried just switching over to see what happens but that does not seem to work. I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from <svc url> If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: <svcurl>    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '<svcurl>'.    The requested service, '<svcurl>' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.HTTP GET Error    URI: <svcurl>    There was an error downloading '<svcurl>'.    The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

I assume this is because I haven't configured an endpoint for the service but the few examples I have seen online do not seem to either.

Has anyone managed to get castle windsor and sharepoint wcf working - preferably with dynamic configuration if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are getting is that the metadata of the service is not published. To do this you need 2 things:

A mex endpoint for your service:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

And service meta data turned on in service behavior:

```
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"  />
```

Comment: Ok, but how should I define the config for the service? At the moment, all my sharepoint wcf services use dynamic configuration based on either MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory and I have added the BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint attribute to the service class to enable the mex endpoint.